# Как своему приложению android дать возможность переноситься на SD-карту?

Tags: android, карты, sd

Не секрет, что некоторые приложения можно переносить на карту памяти, а некоторые нет. Проверив свои программы, я обнаружил, что они не имеют такой возможности. Что нужно сделать что бы она появилась?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно в манифесте указать значение `android:installLocation`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:installLocation="auto">
 ...
</manifest>
```

доступные варианты :
 `auto`- на усмотрение системы
 `internalOnly` - только во внутренюю память
`preferExternal` - по возможности на SD-карту

подробнее смотрите [офф.справку](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)